# Moving picture effect on tile

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation, tiles, windows-phone

I would like to create a tile (not necessary a hub tile, it may be a grid box) for my application. On that tile I want to display a picture and give it a moving effect like the pictures hub. How can I achieve this? Please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Phone 7.5, you can't.  Perhaps in 7.8?  or 8?  But not in anything we have currently.

Comment: cant we create some kind of animation effect which will be equivalent to that effect on the pictures hub?

Comment: No. Sorry.  Best you can do is use a periodic task to change the picture occasionally.  Some "animation" that would be.  ;)

Comment: changing the picture wont give that animation effect.. I am currently researching on that thing. I will post something once I am successful.

Comment: Ummm.... It was tongue in cheek. Hence the smiley. I know that changing a picture about once an hour won't appear animated. Thanks for pointing that out. You won't be successful. It's not possible.  That's why no one else has answered contrary to my answer.